# error when print in mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: javascript, php, html

In this code the countdown will print
The value is from the database, but when printed
He only prints the value of the last row in the first row, not printing the other the values

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dave)) {
 $rows[] = $row; 
} 

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $all=$row['date'];

echo '<h2>'.$row['title'].'</h2>';
    echo '<h4>'.$row['body'].'</h4>'.'<br>'."<script> var res = \"<?php echo $all; ?>\";
var dateVar = res.substring(11, 21); 
var countDownDate=new Date(dateVar).getTime();

var dsplit = dateVar.split(\"-\");
countDownDate=new Date(dsplit[0],dsplit[1]-1,dsplit[2]).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id=\"demo\"
    document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML = days + \"d \" + hours + \"h\"
    + minutes + \"m \" + seconds + \"s\";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML = \"EXPIRED\";
    }
}, 1000);

</script>
";
```

Comment: Why are you using two different loops when you can do it all inside the `while` loop? This is so inefficient. Plus, you shouldn't build your scripts like this, getting elements and values on JavaScript weren't made just to have them, you should use them. It's true, the markup will change, but it makes it more efficient and easy to read.

Comment: I was trying to try to solve the problem

Comment: Well the color coding of that code is a good example of where things have gone wrong ;) Take a look where you have `<?php echo $all; ?>` inside an `echo` already. Thats kinda wrong.

Comment: Okay, one thing that I can tell you to begin with, is that since this is all PHP, you shouldn't do this: `var res = \"<?php echo $all; ?>\";`. Instead, `var res = \"".$all."\";` will work. But I don't see why you made it all between `"` knowing that it would parse it and then fill the entire code with backslashes (can't write them here) in order to escape the `"`. It makes no sense at all and it's hard to read.

Comment: not work invild date